# about pointer array add itself(++)

Tags: c

I don't understand why in the `url_split` function I can use `a++`, but in the `main` function I can't use `key_value++`, they have the same type...

```
void url_split(char *src, char **host, char *a[])    
{
    char const *p1 = "?";
    char const *p2 = "&";

    *host = strtok(src, p1);

    char *str;

    while((str = strtok(NULL, p2))) 
    {
        *a = str;
        a++;   
    }

    *a = str;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])    
{
    char *host;
    char *key_value[100];
    char url[] = "http://www.baidu.com/s?wd=linux&cl=3";

    url_split(url, &host, key_value);

    printf("host = %s\n", host);

    while(*key_value)
    {
        printf("key-value : %s\n", *key_value);
        key_value++; 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They actually don't have the same type:

- `key_value` is of type `char *[100]`, an array of 100 `char` pointers.
- `a` is actually of type `char **`, a pointer to a `char*`, **not** an array.

When you pass `key_value` to `url_split` it decays to a `char**`, which is why `key_value` is a valid argument to the function and why you use `char**` as the type of a function argument that is intended to be an array of `char*`.

The post-increment operator is incompatible with arrays, an array can't be assigned a new value, but it works perfectly fine for pointers, since they can be assigned a new value. That's why `a++` is valid and `key_value++` is not.

Comment: i think it pass the pointer between invoke function,i mean it only copy the address value,because c is passed by value.

Answer (score 3):

No, they are not actually the same thing: `key_value` in `main` is an *array* that you cannot change (you can change the *contents* but not the array variable itself).

When you pass it to a function, it becomes a *pointer* to the first element of that array, which *can* change (to point to other elements of that array, for example).

It's no different to:

```
int xyzzy[10];                  // xyzzy cannot change
int *plugh = xyzzy;             // but plugh can.
```

This "decay" of arrays to pointers actually happens in the vast majority of cases. From the C11 standard:

> Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator or the unary `&` operator, or is a string literal used to initialize an array, an expression that has type "array of type" is converted to an expression with type "pointer to type" that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue. If the array object has register storage class, the behavior is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what is written in Kernighan book about this:

"When an array name is passed to a function, what is passed is the location of the initial element. Within the called function, this argument is a local variable, and so an array name
parameter is a pointer, that is, a variable containing an address."

Which means in main function key_value is an array name, you cannot modify it, since it's just a synonim to the first element in the array. But when passed to function, another pointer is created which points to the same location as first element of array.